# Defining a language in EBNF

Tags: grammar, bnf, ebnf

Give the EBNF specification for the language `L` that is made up of the chars `a`, `b` and `c` such that sentences in the language have the form

```
L : sqsR

-s   is a string of any combination of the characters a and b
-sR  is that same string s reversed
-q   is an  odd number of c's followed by either an odd number of b's
     or an even number of a’s.
```

What I have so far:

```
L -> S
S -> {a}{b}Q
Q ->
```

If this is right, I'm still not really sure how to produce from `Q` and also how to represent `S` in reverse.

Comment: Do your own homework, please.

Comment: Why? You don't like helping students?

Comment: We don't *do* people homework for them around here, but we are willing to help. John has given us an idea of *where* he is stuck so there is a handle on what kind of advice will help without giving him the solutions...

Answer (score 2):

This is a string that starts and ends with the same string, but reversed:

```
X -> aXa
  -> bXb
```

This is a string with an odd number of c's:

```
Y -> cY2
Y2 -> ccY2
```

I've left out some crucial bits, but hopefully this can get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I see how the odd number of c's works but I am a little confused on how that X production works to reverse a string.

Comment: It might help if you try using the X rule to produce a few strings - start with some combination of a's or b's and see what you end up with

Comment: The syntax is just confusing me I think; X -> aXa seems left-recursive, how would you get to -> bXb from that?

Comment: The syntax to me means X is either aXa or bXb, recursively

Answer (score 1):

- Try building the first two parts from the middle out
- You can force an odd number of repetitions by starting with exactly one item and adding N*2 additional items (for integer N). This should suggest how to force an even number as well